# Papervision3D in Flex throws an error when a 3D object is clicked

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, papervision3d

I am working on a game in which there are several Plane objects that the player can click. My main application class extends the BasicView class. I made this whole game as an ActionScript project and everything works fine when I run it as one.

Now I load this game in a Flex application. When added to the Flex application, it runs perfectly until I click somewhere at which point it throws the following error:

```
undefined
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils.virtualmouse::VirtualMouse/update()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\virtualmouse\VirtualMouse.as:562]
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils.virtualmouse::VirtualMouse/press()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\virtualmouse\VirtualMouse.as:451]
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils::InteractiveSceneManager/handleMousePress()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\InteractiveSceneManager.as:189]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/mouseEventHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2924]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils.virtualmouse::VirtualMouse/handleUpdate()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\virtualmouse\VirtualMouse.as:724]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils.virtualmouse::VirtualMouse/update()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\virtualmouse\VirtualMouse.as:562]
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils.virtualmouse::VirtualMouse/press()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\virtualmouse\VirtualMouse.as:451]
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils::InteractiveSceneManager/handleMousePress()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\InteractiveSceneManager.as:189]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/mouseEventHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2924]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils.virtualmouse::VirtualMouse/handleUpdate()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\virtualmouse\VirtualMouse.as:724]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils.virtualmouse::VirtualMouse/update()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\virtualmouse\VirtualMouse.as:562]
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils.virtualmouse::VirtualMouse/press()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\virtualmouse\VirtualMouse.as:451]
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils::InteractiveSceneManager/handleMousePress()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\InteractiveSceneManager.as:189]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/mouseEventHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2924]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils.virtualmouse::VirtualMouse/handleUpdate()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\virtualmouse\VirtualMouse.as:724]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils.virtualmouse::VirtualMouse/update()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\virtualmouse\VirtualMouse.as:562]
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils.virtualmouse::VirtualMouse/press()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\virtualmouse\VirtualMouse.as:451]
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils::InteractiveSceneManager/handleMousePress()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\InteractiveSceneManager.as:189]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/mouseEventHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2924]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils.virtualmouse::VirtualMouse/handleUpdate()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\virtualmouse\VirtualMouse.as:724]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils.virtualmouse::VirtualMouse/update()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\virtualmouse\VirtualMouse.as:562]
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils.virtualmouse::VirtualMouse/press()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\virtualmouse\VirtualMouse.as:451]
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils::InteractiveSceneManager/handleMousePress()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\InteractiveSceneManager.as:189]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/mouseEventHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2924]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils.virtualmouse::VirtualMouse/handleUpdate()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\virtualmouse\VirtualMouse.as:724]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils.virtualmouse::VirtualMouse/update()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\virtualmouse\VirtualMouse.as:562]
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils.virtualmouse::VirtualMouse/press()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\virtualmouse\VirtualMouse.as:451]
    at org.papervision3d.core.utils::InteractiveSceneManager/handleMousePress()[D:\Omer Hassan\our5pillars\repository\flash\game\src\org\papervision3d\core\utils\InteractiveSceneManager.as:189]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/mouseEventHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2924]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an if statement near org\papervision3d\core\utils\InteractiveSceneManager.as:189 which I had to comment and then it started working.